# What object type is used for a single related image property in Sitefinity?

Tags: c#, sitefinity, sitefinity-feather, sitefinity-mvc

I've added a custom field to the news widget called **RelatedImage** which I want to display in a custom News List MVC template.

**Note:** the custom field is a Related media (images, videos, files) field with the limitation of "Multiple images can be uploaded or selected" set.

I can retrieve the image's URL by looping through custom field as follows:

```
@foreach (var relatedItem in item.Fields.RelatedImage)
{
    <li>@relatedItem.Fields.MediaUrl</li>
}
```

The above code works and renders the URL.

Code like this outputs the correct value:

```
@item.Fields.RelatedImage.Length
```

However, when you set the limitation to "Only 1 image can be uploaded or selected" the model used for `@item.Fields.RelatedImage` changes so the above code throws exceptions because those properties don't exist.

What I need though is to render out only one image per news item in the list, but when I switch to the "Only 1 image..." limitation mode, I can't figure out what the model looks like or how to get a hold of its properties. So the following code won't work:

```
@item.RelatedItem("RelatedImage").Fields.MediaUrl
```

So the question for me right now is a frustrating one: How do I know what model is passed to my template/view? I've tried outputting various `GetType().ToString()` options but all i repeatedly get is ItemViewModel which doesn't help!

**Edit - The following code actually works:**

```
<img src="@Html.Raw(item.Fields.RelatedImage.Fields.MediaUrl)" />
```

But this was frustratingly difficult to figure out. How does one figure out what Type RelatedImage is. The property Fields is of type dynamic which makes things more tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `RelatedImage` field is set to allow 1 image, the value returned will be of type `Telerik.Sitefinity.Libraries.Model.Image`.

If the field is set to allow multiple images, the value returned will be an array of the same type i.e. `Telerik.Sitefinity.Libraries.Model.Image[]`

To answer your question, you could check the type of the `RelatedImage` property:

```
@if (item.Fields.RelatedImage is Image)
{
    <img src="item.Fields.RelatedImage.Fields.MediaUrl" />
}
else if (item.Fields.RelatedImage is Image[])
{
    foreach (var relatedItem in item.Fields.RelatedImage)
    {
        <img src="relatedItem.Fields.MediaUrl" />
    } 
}
```

A better way might be to use the `GetRelatedItems` extension found in `Telerik.Sitefinity.RelatedData.RelatedDataExtensions` when building your view model e.g.

```
viewModel.RelatedImages = newsItem.GetRelatedItems<Image>("RelatedImage")
```

which would return a collection of Image objects, regardless of the number of images selected.

Comment: Thanks @OllieP. Question, where did you get this kind of clear information from? I looked through Telerik's documentation and found nothing of the sort.

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation is disappointingly lacking. You can use the Sitefinity forums and normally get a response within a few days. A bit of experimentation and a copy of dotPeek to have a nosy round the dlls is the alternative if you don't know anyone with existing knowledge.